# Upgrade to Mac OS El Capitan, intellij zoom stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running intellij 14.1.5 and recently updated my Mac Air to El Capitan OS version.

I used to be able to use the gestures to increase the editor font size and now it has stopped working.

I found the accessibility pane in preferences on the Mac and set zoom there so the gesture works everywhere BUT intellij.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they do not support EI yet. Check out the [system requirements](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/system_requirements.jsp?os=mac):

> Mac OS X 10.5 or higher, up to 10.9 (Mavericks)
>
> 1 GB RAM minimum, 2 GB RAM recommended
>
> 300 MB hard disk space + at least 1 GB for caches
>
> 1024x768 minimum screen resolution Java 6

There is a suggestion you can try beta version of IntelliJ IDEA 15. if you are a developer, you better keep you system in stable version because upgrade to new version of system software company need time to upgrade there software to support the new system.

Comment: I thought there might be a workaround.  I will wait for 15 to come out.  Should be soon